# How to run pg_bulkload on windows?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible somehow to run the postgres batch tool `pg_bulkload` on windows? I could not find any documentation on this, only for linux.

Though it should be possible as the docs state:

> If you use pg_bulkload in Windows operating system, postgresql script
>   is not included in a pg_bulkload package. So you have to invoke
>   "pg_bulkload -r" manually.

Finally it should be triggered from inside a java tool, which itself also has to run on the same machine.

Comment: From what I see on the project page, this product is not extremely stable (see the notes about 3.1.7).  Are you sure the regular `COPY` functionality is not enough for you?

Comment: Well, it depends wether the import using `pg_bulkload` would be much faster than `COPY`. The docs suggest improvements of about 50%, which would be enough for me to make the switch.

Comment: How much data do you import normally (in number of rows and/or physical size)?  On an other note, if it crashes your server than you don't get too far with the time spared on the load.

Comment: It's about 300mio rows and 150 GB, 2-3 times a day. Yes, probably you're right it won't give me much improvement if I'd have to worry about stability all the time...

Comment: Then I understand why you are concerned about time :)

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2022, pg_bulkload C application is NOT supported on the Windows kernel.  It is only supported on Linux kernel.  This is documented from 2016 and I've tested this month to confirm with the latest compiled source code.

https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_bulkload/issues/15

The client `\COPY` and server `COPY` command are also written in C, and will run on Windows.  As you can see, much of the pg_bulkload source code was written based on COPY, but bypasses two types of buffers (shared and WAL).  WAL buffer is a feature to PostgreSQL.  From my understanding, someone would need to find a similar solution on Windows with Buffered I/O and/or Direct I/O.

https://doxygen.postgresql.org/bin_2psql_2copy_8c_source.html

MakeFile compiles and installs pg_bulkload, so this would need to be configured for Windows, among other libraries within pg_bulkload.  In Windows, you must do the following for MakeFile.

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```